# Introspy: trace file (introspy.db) is not created

Tags: applications, android-emulator

I am trying to use [Introspy](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android) tool in Android device, but the trace file (`introspy.db`) is not being created. Kindly any help if you have tried using this.

Comment: Is your device definitely rooted? And are you looking in the private directory of the app you're analysing, not the config app? And finally, what has your question to do with the emulator?

Comment: yes device is rooted , i am looking into app's file system only not into the intorspy app's directory..  for example com.example.test is my app, i am looking into /data/data/com.example.test folder...

Comment: Consider to post a new issue [on their issue tracker](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android/issues) to let the developers know about it. Probably, the error is not on user-side, but developer-side.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago but in case anyone else who searches needs an answer:

I also had this problem when running Introspy on a Galaxy S4 running KitKat (4.4.2).  I have ran Introspy with zero problems on a Nexus S running JellyBean (4.2.1).  Because of this I believe it is an Android SDK problem with newer versions.

If you look at the AndroidManifest file for Introspy-Android Core, the targetSdkVersion is 18, which denotes Jellybean.  I looked at logcat files and found that I was getting the error:

```
Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

I simply added this permission to the Android Core AndroidManifest.xml file as well as the Android Config AndroidManifest.xml with the command:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

I then just recompiled both binaries and it worked!  Hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know it works! Consider to create a pull request.